# Php get current locale for LC_MONETARY

Tags: php, locale

I'm using this code to display an amount in the current locale.

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'it_IT');
echo money_format('%i', $number);
```

My question is, how can I see the current value for LC_MONETARY ? If I do a simple echo the value seems the same and I can't find any getlocale function.

```
echo LC_MONETARY;
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'it_IT');
echo LC_MONETARY;
```

Update : LC_MONETARY is the category of function affected so it makes sense the value is the same. But how can I see the current locale info then ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$oldLocale = setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'it_IT');
// setlocale() will return the old value if the locale could 
// be set (return value greatly depends on the system's underlying 
// setlocale() implementation)

$oldLocale = setlocale(LC_MONETARY, '0');
// using '0' as the locale-argument will result in the current setting 
//being returned without affecting the locale setting itself
```

See the note for the `$locale` parameter in the [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/setlocale) documentation.

Comment: I wonder if that's `'0'` or `0`. +1 anyway for properly reading the docs. :) It does *not always* return the old locale though, I initially misread that as well.

Comment: It's important to use `'0'`, aka the string `0`, because `0`, aka the integer `0`, will be interpreted as `false` (as will `NULL` or the empty string `''`) which won't trigger the same behavior. It'll set the locale according to the environment though. But I suppose that this may be system-dependent as well.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the constant `LC_MONETARY` will never change. When setting a locale with `setlocale(LC_MONETARY, ...)`, you're not changing the `LC_MONETARY` constant, you're setting the locale for the *"monetary" category*. This locale setting happens in the background and is not visible outwardly. The `LC_MONETARY` constant is just an identifier for the category.

Usually you don't need to know what's currently set. You should simply set your desired locale when needed.

Comment: $previousLocale returns the new current local

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `localeconv()` function (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php):

```
print_r(localeconv());
```

Outputs (depending on what you set with `setlocale()`):

```
Array
(
    [decimal_point] => .
    [thousands_sep] =>
    [int_curr_symbol] => EUR
    [currency_symbol] => €
    [mon_decimal_point] => ,
    [mon_thousands_sep] =>
    [positive_sign] =>
    [negative_sign] => -
    [int_frac_digits] => 2
    [frac_digits] => 2
    [p_cs_precedes] => 1
    [p_sep_by_space] => 1
    [n_cs_precedes] => 1
    [n_sep_by_space] => 1
    [p_sign_posn] => 1
    [n_sign_posn] => 2
    [grouping] => Array
        (
        )

    [mon_grouping] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

The main thing you'll probably care about is the `int_curr_symbol` result.

```
$data = localeconv();
$symbol = $data['int_curr_symbol'];

switch($symbol){
    case 'EUR':
        // Euro
        break;

    case 'USD':
        // US Dollars
        break;

    // ...
}
```